# Удалённый дебаг Java приложения

Tags: java, отладка, vps, remote-debugging

Есть VPS сервер на Debian 9. На сервере крутится одно самописное Java приложение. Версия Java - 11. Спустя пару месяцев заметил, что некоторые функции приложения работают нестабильно. По внутреннему мониторингу используемой памяти увидел утечку в 400 мегабайт. В короткосрочной перспективе неоднократно (рестарты приложения только при наличии обновлений), до 50 дней, таких вещей замечено не было. Сборщик мусора всегда держал текущий размер приложения в одном и том же интервале.

Хотелось бы определиться - это моё упущение в коде создало такую утечку памяти или VPS сервис предоставляется не совсем честно и runtime приложение может работать нестабильно.

Вопрос: есть ли инструменты для удалённого дебага Java приложений?

Comment: Удаленный дебаг можно соорудить, используя джавовский remote debugging + ssh туннель aka проброс порта. Вот есть статья, где все описано:
https://arjon.es/2014/remote-debug-of-a-java-app-using-ssh-tunneling-without-opening-server-ports/

Comment: @iksuy т.е. в параметрах запуска должен быть предопределён режим дебаггера? А без перезапуска приложения никак?

Comment: Я знаю только такой способ, требует перезапуска. Может кто подскажет что-нибудь более толковое. Можно еще покопать профилировщики, но вроде там везде тоже нужно запускать приложение с профайл-агентами в параметрах, т.е. опять же перезапуск.

Comment: @iksuy оформите пожалуйста как предполагаемый ответ. Возможно пригодится не только мне. Если вариантов не будет больше, то отмечу его как приемлемый для меня.

Comment: А для начала встроенными средствами вы пробовали решить проблему? jmap, visualvm с пробросом порта и прочее? Я так понимаю вам больше не отладка нужна, а профилировщик.

Comment: @iksuy VisualVM я использовал только на локальном компьютере. Про удалённое подключение я даже не слышал. У меня был небольшой опыт дебага с разбором и анализом дампа в Memory Analyzer (MAT). Но это было давно и на локальной машине. В итоге я ничего криминального не нашёл и забил на это.